# D3js: how to get Lat/Log geocoordinates from mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, topojson

Using some D3js code and projected topojson data on a map dataviz of [any projection](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/azimuthal.html), how can I get back geocoordinates ? Something such:

```
var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg:svg")
 .attr("width", 320)
 .attr("height", 200)
 .on("mousedown", mousedown)
 .on("click", mouselocation);
```

**How to get the geocordinates from a click on a D3js map visualisation ?**

Links to demos welcome.

---

**Edit:** a list of relevant demos :

- [OpenLayers demo](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html)... but we what D3js.
- [Jason Davies/rotate/](http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/) use of `projection.invert(d3.mouse(this))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_mouse) to get the pixel coordinates, and then use the projection ([d3.geo.azimuthal](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-azimuthal), here) to invert *x* and *y* to longitude and latitude. For example:

```
d3.select("svg").on("mousedown.log", function() {
  console.log(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)));
});
```

If you want to support clicking on the background of the SVG, you may also want an invisible rect with pointer-events: all. (Also note: older versions of D3 used d3.svg.mouse rather than d3.mouse.)

Comment: can you post an example of how to add an invisible rect which can be clickable?

Comment: hi thanks, ok i think i have it, although it does not seem to respond on the click immediately. could you look at it http://bl.ocks.org/2876083 perhaps i have missed something.

Comment: Note, in later versions `d3.mouse` has changed to `d3.pointer`.

Answer (score 0):

[Jason Davies/rotate/](http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/) use of `projection.invert(d3.mouse(this))` is nice and may worth a look.

`.on("mousedown.grab", function() {
   var point;
   if (mousePoint) point = svg.insert("path", ".foreground")
             .datum({type: "Point", coordinates: projection.invert(d3.mouse(this))})
             .attr("class", "point")
             .attr("d", path); // add back the point`